# Search for issues with custom field of type "Multi-Checkboxes" not ticked

Tags: jira

In our Jira we have a custom field of type "Multi-Checkboxes".  How can I search for issues which do not have a checkbox checked?  Issues with nothing checked would do, since this is the only checkbox.

I can search for issues with the checkbox checked with a simple query:

```
Colour = "Red"
```

But nothing I can think of will find issues where it is not checked.  I have tried the following:

```
Colour != "Red"
Colour = ""
Colour is not "Red"
Colour not in ("Red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer just after posting:

```
Colour is EMPTY
```

Comment: That wouldn't scale if you have other check boxes for this multiple, and you still only want to find those that do not have "Red" checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple checkboxes and want to find issues where "Red" has not been checked you could do ... Colour is EMPTY OR Colour != "Red"

Answer (score 1):

**This will bring up any checklists that have NO checklist items entered.**

Checkbox = EMPTY

**IF you want to see things that aren't checked use the following:**

type = "Task" and !("ChecklistName[Checkboxes]" = Yes)

-*Where Yes above is the item you're looking to see is unchecked. However, it wants to be sure something else IS CHECKED.

**ALTERNATE**

type = Task AND NOT "ChecklistName[Checkboxes]" = Yes

NOTE - I use Jira Cloud

Answer (score 0):

`Colour IS EMPTY` has an implicit check that the "Colour" field exists, so it won't return issues that don't have anything defined.

I had the following situation:

1. Tickets already existed.
2. I created a new "Checkbox" custom field.
3. Searching `Colour IS EMPTY` returned no results, which was unexpected.
4. I reindexed the project
5. Searching `Colour IS EMPTY` returned results as expected

Answer (score 0):

Do the below for each item in your checklist (If you want to see which items are not checked):

{{#if(issue."Checklist Custom Field".value.indexOf("Item in Checklist").max.eq(-1))}} Item in Checklist was NOT checked {{/}}

Comment: Please properly format your code in answers. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).